# Python3: ssl cert information

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, urllib

I have been trying to get information regarding expired ssl certificates using python 3 but it would be nice to be able to get as verbose a workup as possible.  any takers?
So far i have been trying to use urllib.request to get this info (to no avail), does this strike anyone as foolish?

I have seen some examples of similar work using older versions of python, but nothing using v3.
http://objectmix.com/python/737581-re-urllib-getting-ssl-certificate-info.html
http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg208150.html

Answer (score 1):

The 3.1.1 documentation for SSL has an [example](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/ssl.html#client-side-operation).